# Load extension dynamically

Tags: php

I use shared hosting, here is not enabled PDO driver for postgresql DB

There is possible to load driver dynamically?

P.S.
I am trying:

```
if (!extension_loaded('php_pdo_pgsql')) {
    dl('php_pdo_pgsql.dll');
}
```

This gives `Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl()`

Is there another way?

Comment: What's your PHP version ? (dl function was disable from Php 5.3) - according to php 5.3 documentation, only php-cli can use dl function with the default php.ini.

Comment: It wasn't removed...but disabled by default.

Comment: If youre using shared hosting your chances are very low to do this on your very own. Best is to contact your provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot load extensions dynamically starting from PHP 5.3.0 (except in specific contexts that do not apply in this case).

Your only option is to talk to your host and ask them to enable the extension for you.

Comment: you could implement the PostgreSQL client protocol with tcp sockets if you really have to... but that would be a big time-consuming task, and not for the faint of heart

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs: http://php.net/dl

dl() has been removed from some SAPIs (e.g. apache, iis, etc) as of PHP 5.3.0