# Is there any way to enable pdo_mysql within a php file?

Tags: php, linux, pdo

After I uploaded my php files to the server, I received a message...

**PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => could not find driver**

I know there is a solution.

Just add "extension=pdo.so" and "extension=pdo_mysql.so" in php.ini

but I am not permitted to change php.ini or to access the Linux server, which really distressed me.

**Is there a solution to install pdo_mysql in my php files? (not php.ini )**

I just need my files to be enabled to use PDO.

And the version is **PHP Version 5.5.38**

Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler

Thank you.

Comment: There is https://secure.php.net/dl but it's likely blocked or removed from your version of PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load extension dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123754/load-extension-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dl.

```
dl('/path/to/pdo_mysql.so');
```

but be warned that dl is disabled in many php environments (like shared hosting providers, apache's mod_php, the `enable_dl` php.ini directive, and <strike>php-fpm</strike> - edit: dl was disabled in php-fpm at 7.0, but should work in 5.5)

Comment: Sadly, I received this "Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl()"
It seems like it's been removed after php5.3

Comment: @PeterTsai it was removed from apache's mod_php in 5.3, but it still exists in php-fpm and php-cli in 5.5 - and it was removed from php-fpm in 7.0, but it still exists in php-cli.

Comment: @PeterTsai if you're using mod_php, then add that information to your original post

Comment: Are you talking about this "Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler" ??